# How to add scroll empty space in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When you do `find /` in the native ubuntu terminal it prints output till the  end of the screen. After this there is no empty scroll space available to scroll down. I temporarily solved this problem by `clear` function which adds additional scroll space. I do python programming in terminal and in it this doesn't work

```
for a in range(1000):
    print(a)
```

How I can hard code terminal to get some scroll empty space for both bash and python?

Comment: What do you have your terminal profile scroll buffer set to?  Scrolling in such a situation is the default.

Comment: Mine is limited to 8192 lines

Comment: My Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-terminal (3.28.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) is not limited, up to 100k lines, which is all I've tested for. What release are you running, and which terminal version/package?

Comment: 3.18.3 ubuntu 16.04. Even python programme which prints less than 1000 lines has the same problem

Comment: I'm also on 16.04 and your python code works fine with scroll back for me in gnome-terminal.

Comment: As far as I understand, your problem is that there is no empty space _under_ the output of your utilities. New lines will automatically appear there and the existing content will scroll upwards whenever needed. What is your actual problem, what is it that doesn't work for you?

Comment: `your problem is that there is no empty space under the output of your utilities. New lines will automatically appear there and the existing content will scroll upwards whenever needed.` this is it. I need empyt space below my last output line

Comment: @Eka Why do you need empty space?

Comment: Did you mean printing some empty strings like `echo " "` in bash and `print("")` in python.

Comment: @wjandrea I do lots of stuff with terminal and like my command centered to the screen and to my eyeline. I know it may feel odd to many but currently it feels like I am stuck at the bottom of the terminal with only one way to move ie downwards.

Comment: @Kulfy No thats not what i want

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1106674/how-to-add-blank-lines-above-the-bottom-in-terminal.

Comment: @egmont thank you that was a good solution but do we have anything similar for python.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want three extra lines below your prompt.

In **Bash**, run this, and from then on, you will have the three extra lines:

```
PS1+="\[\eD\eD\eD\e[3A\]"
```

To make it permanent, put it in your `~/.bashrc`.

---

The equivalent in **Python** uses [`sys.ps1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.ps1):

```
import sys
sys.ps1 += '\x01\x1bD\x1bD\x1bD\x1b[3A\x02'
```

Or you could move the number of extra lines into a variable:

```
_ps1_extra_lines = 3
sys.ps1 += '\x01' + '\x1bD' * _ps1_extra_lines + '\x1b[A' * _ps1_extra_lines + '\x02'
```

To make it permanent, put it in a [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) file, which you may need to set up first.

Also note this is meant for the regular Python shell, and will not work in IPython, for example.

---

For explanation and more details, see [How to add blank lines above the bottom in terminal - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1106674/how-to-add-blank-lines-above-the-bottom-in-terminal).

Comment: I like a blank line **before** my prompt rather than after.

Comment: @Win Me too, but that's too easy ;)